# FireBug: How can I get rid of annoying messages?

Tags: jquery, firefox, firebug

FireBug always shows warning messages from jQuery
eg

```
reference to undefined property o.cache[H][E]
(function(){var l=this,g,y=l.jQuery,p=...ch(function(){o.dequeue(this,E)})}}); jquery.min.js (string 12)
```

Can I set up FireBug not to show certain warnings for certain scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that warning will go away if you use:
Firebug > Console Panel > Mini-menu on tab > Strict Warnings OFF

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is an issue with either jQuery or Firebug. Debug your code and find out what's leading to the error / warning.

Comment: @sallake , as Phil said some of your code is throwing error. Please check your javascript code otherwise it will create problems in future.