# Unable to reset/rectifiy Firefox warnings

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

After debugging I was not able to reset the warnings found from error console of Firefox. Please guide me to make necessary changes.

Below mentioned is the code

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/jquery.dimensions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/jquery.datepick.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css"> 
    @import url('include/flora.datepick.css');
    @import url('include/mainstyle.css');
</style>
</head><body>
<div id="framecontentTop">
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="1250" height="100">
  <param name="movie" value="test5.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
     <embed src="test5.swf"
      quality="high"
      type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
      WMODE="transparent"
      width="1250"
      height="100"
      pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
      allowScriptAccess="always" />
</object>
</div>
<div align="left" ></div>
   <div id="framecontentLeft">
    <div id="floatMenu">
                <ul class="menu1"> <li><a href="jobs.php" class="active" onMouseOver="window.status='Now your here'; return true;" onMouseOut="window.status='';" > Jobs Home</a></li> </ul>
<?php if($login_val[1]<=3){ ?>
                <ul class="menu3"> <li><a href="page_cnd.php" onMouseOver="window.status='Corporate networking'; return true;" onMouseOut="window.status='';" >Corp Net</a></li></ul>
                <ul class="menu4"> <li><a href="page_isy.php" onMouseOver="window.status='List of Login Tracking'; return true;" onMouseOut="window.status='';" > MIS </a></li> </ul>
                <ul class="menu5"> <li><a href="page_ope.php" onMouseOver="window.status='Center Lists'; return true;" onMouseOut="window.status='';" > Operations </a></li> </ul>
                <ul class="menu6"> <li><a href="page_res.php" onMouseOver="window.status='Center Lists'; return true;" onMouseOut="window.status='';" > HR </a></li> </ul>
                <ul class="menu7"> <li><a href="page_trk.php" onMouseOver="window.status='Center Lists'; return true;" onMouseOut="window.status='';" > User Tracking</a></li> </ul>
                <ul class="menu8"> <li><a href="page_dum.php" onMouseOver="window.status='Center Lists'; return true;" onMouseOut="window.status='';" > RESERVED </a></li> </ul>
<?php } ?>
<?php if($login_val[1]<=0){ ?>
                <ul class="menu15"> <li><a href="login_tab_master.php" onMouseOver="window.status='Hello administrator'; return true;" onMouseOut="window.status='';" > Administrator </a></li> </ul>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<div id="loginline" align="center"> <?php echo "<strong><span class='welnote'>(- Welcome -) </span><br><em><span class='visnote'>$login_val[0]</span></em></strong>"; ?></div>
   </div>
<div id="maincontent">
        <div id="underlinemenu" align="right">
        <ul><li><a href="clie_lead_conv_tab_master.php"  onMouseOver="window.status='Leads converted into placements information'; return true;" onMouseOut="window.status='';" >leads converted</a></li>

            <li style="float:right"><a href="logout.php" onClick="alert('Yep ! you are out of Website - Status on Activites ');" onMouseOver="window.status='Exit DRF-DOL with you ID'; return true;" onMouseOut="window.status='';" >LogOut/Exit</a></li>
            <li style="float:right"><a href="#" id="update_pbutton" name="update_pbutton" onMouseOver="window.status='Chage password and Visible name of your ID'; return true;" onMouseOut="window.status='';" > Security </a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sorton"  ALIGN = "center"> 
            <form id="sort_form" class="sort_form" method="post">
                <label for="sort_one">Sort jobs by :</label><select name="sort_one" id="sort_one">
                    <option value="">Select</option> <option value="cour_name">Domain</option> <option value="loca_name">Location</option> <option value="net_sal">Salary</option> <option value="qual">Qualification</option> <option value="posi">Designation</option> </select>
                <label for="sort_two">then by :</label><select name="sort_two" id="sort_two">
                    <option value="">Select</option> <option value="cour_name">Domain</option> <option value="loca_name">Location</option> <option value="net_sal">Salary</option> <option value="qual">Qualification</option> <option value="posi">Designation</option> </select>
                <label for="sort_three">then by :</label><select name="sort_three" id="sort_three">
                    <option value="">Select</option> <option value="cour_name">Domain</option> <option value="loca_name">Location</option> <option value="net_sal">Salary</option> <option value="qual">Qualification</option> <option value="posi">Designation</option> </select>
                <label for="sort_four">then by :</label><select name="sort_four" id="sort_four">
                    <option value="">Select</option> <option value="cour_name">Domain</option> <option value="loca_name">Location</option> <option value="net_sal">Salary</option> <option value="qual">Qualification</option> <option value="posi">Designation</option> </select>
                <input type="submit" value=" Show "/>
            </form>
        </div>
    <div class="update_pform"></div>
        <div class="container">  
            <div class="firstform"></div> 
                        <div class="name_list"></div>
        </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

// my start
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("form#sort_form").submit(function(){
    //this loads the update form
            var sortone = $('#sort_one').attr('value');
            var sorttwo = $('#sort_two').attr('value');
            var sortthree = $('#sort_three').attr('value');
            var sortfour = $('#sort_four').attr('value');
            alert(sortone + " - " + sorttwo + " - " + sortthree + " - " + sortfour );
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "jobs_load-list.php",
                    data: "sort_one="+ sortone +"& sort_two="+ sorttwo +"& sort_three="+ sortthree + "& sort_four="+ sortfour,
                    cache: false,
                    success : function(html){
                            $(".name_list").html(html);
                            }
                       });
            return false;
        });

    $.fn.clearForm = function() {
          return this.each(function() {
            var type = this.type, tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
            if (tag == 'form')
              return $(':input',this).clearForm();
            if (type == 'text' || type == 'password' || tag == 'textarea')
              this.value = '';
            else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio')
              this.checked = false;
            else if (tag == 'select')
              this.selectedIndex = -1;
          });
        };


        // load list start
        function loadList(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "jobs_load-list.php",
                    cache: false,
                    success : function(html){
                            $(".name_list").html(html);
                            $(".firstform").show();
                            $(".update_pform").show();
                                }
                       });
                }

loadList();


//this loads the Pupdate form

     $("a#update_pbutton").live("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var x=window.confirm("Are you sure you want to update this Activity?");
        if (x==true){
            $.ajax({
                url: "update-pform.php",
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                        $(".update_pform").html(html);
                        $(".firstform").hide();
                        $(".name_list").hide();
                                }
                       });
                }
            return false;
        });

    $("form#updatepform").live("change","submit", function(){
            var pass = $('#pa_pupdate').attr('value'); 
        var lev = $('#ulev_pupdate').attr('value');
        var idpvaluein = $('#id_pupdate').attr('value');
        var x=window.confirm("Are you sure you want to update password ?");
            if (x==true){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "updatep.php",
                data: "pass="+ pass_update +"& id="+ idpvaluein+"& ulev="+ ulevel_update,
                cache: false,
                success: function(){
                          $(".update_pform").empty();
                        $(".firstform").show();
                        $(".name_list").show();
                    loadList();
                }
            }); 
            }
             return false;  
        });
});
</script>
```

Below mentiond are the errors found in error console of Firefox

1. Warning: function Ka does not always
   return a value Source File:
       http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.min.js
       Line: 18, Column: 446
2. Warning: test for equality (==)
           mistyped as assignment (=)? Source
           File:
           http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.min.js
           Line: 20, Column: 19
3. Warning: test for equality (==)
       mistyped as assignment (=)? Source
       File:
       http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.min.js
       Line: 24, Column: 299
4. Warning: anonymous function does not
           always return a value Source File:
           http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.min.js
           Line: 29, Column: 229
5. Warning: anonymous function does not
           always return a value Source File:
           http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.min.js
           Line: 30, Column: 93
6. Warning: anonymous function does not
           always return a value Source File:
           http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.min.js
           Line: 31, Column: 461
7. Warning: anonymous function does not
           always return a value Source File:
           http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.min.js
           Line: 43, Column: 247
8. Warning: anonymous function does
    not
            always return a value Source File:
            http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.min.js
            Line: 46, Column: 103
9. Warning: test for equality (==)
        mistyped as assignment (=)? Source
        File:
        http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.min.js
        Line: 56, Column: 228
10. Warning: test for equality (==)
         mistyped as assignment (=)? Source
         File:
         http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.min.js
         Line: 59, Column: 70
11. Warning: test for equality (==)
         mistyped as assignment (=)? Source
         File:
         http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.min.js
         Line: 60, Column: 8
12. Warning: test for equality (==)
         mistyped as assignment (=)? Source
         File:
         http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.min.js
         Line: 62, Column: 166
13. Warning: anonymous function does
     not
         always return a value Source File:
         http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.min.js
         Line: 67, Column: 24
14. Warning: anonymous function does
     not
         always return a value Source File:
         http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.min.js
         Line: 69, Column: 400
15. Warning: anonymous function does
     not
         always return a value Source File:
         http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.min.js
         Line: 71, Column: 422
16. Warning: anonymous function does
     not
         always return a value Source File:
         http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.min.js
         Line: 74, Column: 457
17. Warning: test for equality (==)
         mistyped as assignment (=)? Source
         File:
         http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.min.js
         Line: 79, Column: 465
18. Warning: anonymous function does
     not
         always return a value Source File:
         http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.form.js
         Line: 360, Column: 2 Source Code: };
19. Warning: anonymous function does
     not
         always return a value Source File:
         http://localhost/drf-dol/login_tab_master.php
         Line: 155, Column: 31 Source Code:
             });
20. Warning: reference to undefined
         property a[c.expando] Source File:
         http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.min.js
         Line: 42
21. Warning: reference to undefined
         property j[++H] Source File:
         http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.min.js
         Line: 33
22. Warning: reference to undefined
         property b.dataType Source File:
         http://localhost/drf-dol/include/jquery.min.js
         Line: 140

Comment: If you will post the warnings/errors we might be able to help you fix them.

Comment: Shadpw wizard forgot to include!! Now i have updated the same with errors...Please guide me..

Comment: most of these come from the "core" of jQuery, try updating to the latest jQuery version and see if it helps.

Comment: Shadow!! please check point no 18 19 20 you can notice that some thing gone wrong... with your suggestion i am using the latest version of jquery.. Still the same thing is repeated

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just hide those warnings (rather than fix them) see this post:
[FireBug: How can I get rid of annoying messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038561/firebug-how-can-i-get-rid-of-annoying-messages)